# With that or without "that", which one is more formal to write?

Tags: relative-pronouns, formality, optional-that

I have this sentence:

> There is an engine inside me **that** keeps saying "someone must be at the top, why isn't that you?"

Should I write *that* or leave it out?

I know both ways are correct, but I am asking for the most most most most most formal way.

Comment: As a native American English speaker, the sentence would sound awkward without "that" to modify "keeps."  Either "There is an engine inside me, saying...'"  or, "There is an engine inside me that keeps saying..." would sound natural, but "There is an engine inside me keeps saying..." sounds off.

Comment: @jwpat7 where is the capitalization please? i have to capital just the `There`, am i right? please help me in these things, i have test in 1 month

Comment: Capitalize I when it's a personal pronoun.  Get rid of extra *most*'s.  Fix misspelling of *formal*.

Comment: @jwpat7 ok I will, also please tell me should i capitaize the `someone` in my sentence or not?

Comment: @Lumberjack, regarding the form without *that* as sounding off, it may be slightly more precise to say it is nonstandard – ie, might be regarded as a sign of illiteracy or poor language skills or carelessness; or in the hands of some authors, a sign of art.

Comment: @jwpat7 what about `someone` please

Comment: Marco,  *someone* should be capitalized because it's the first word of a quoted sentence.

Comment: Actually I don't think it is correct to remove *that* here...  There are certainly some cases where you can, but *that* doesn't always have the same usage/meaning, and I'm pretty sure it is required here. (It certainly sounds wrong without it to me!)

Comment: I believe you are also supposed to set the quotation off with a comma before.

Comment: @jwpat7 what do you think about what Tyler James Young has said please?

Comment: [Cross-posting the exact same question to both ELU and ELL](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134010/with-that-or-without-the-most-formal-way) without telling people you've done so is considered abusive. Please don't do it.

Comment: Marco, re comma before quote, see eg  [Use of commas before a quote](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/113850).  I'd say no comma before the quote in the example in the question.  Note, *someone* still needs to be capitalized.

Comment: (Not, mind you, that it would be appropriate if you **did** tell people.  But it would be somewhat less abusive.)

Answer (score 4):

You can't omit *that* when it's a subject, or your sentence becomes ungrammatical in standard English.

In this case, *that* is the subject of a *that*-relative clause:

> There is an engine inside me
>   　　[ **that** keeps saying "someone must be at the top, why isn't that you?" ]<sub>*that*-relative clause</sub>

In particular, it's the subject of the verb *keeps*.  So you can't omit it, and there's no formal vs. informal distinction to be made.

Comment: I won't actually *downvote*, because there's a lot of truth in what you say. But I think it's a bit OTT to say you ***can't*** delete relative pronouns serving as subjects. People do it all the time, particularly in casual speech. It's just that in OP's exact context, it's not *suitable* if he wants to be meticulously "formal and correct".

Comment: Well, obviously you **can** do anything you want.  You can say "I go store.  Thog proud go store!"  But it's **non-standard** to omit *that* when it's a subject.

Comment: This one will run and run. You think there's a set of rules called ***grammar*** which somehow exist in a context beyond actual ***usage***, whereas I think grammar is more a post-hoc attempt to codify pre-existing usage. Your straw man examples would be considered "ignorant/illiterate" by any native speaker, but let's face it - who but the most extreme pedant would seriously take issue with ["There was a time I wanted {to have children}"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22There+was+a+time+I+wanted%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example?

Comment: @FumbleFingers *That* isn't a subject in your example.  It's the non-*wh* counterpart of "**when** I wanted to have children" → "I wanted to have children **then**", where the gap represents an **adjunct of time**; it's replaced by *that*, which is fronted and then deleted, which is possible because it's not a subject.  (And your comment is a mischaracterization.)

Comment: On thinking a bit more sensibly, I accept that you're far more right than me on this issue. I won't actually *delete* my answer, because I don't think it's entirely wrong, but I'll edit a note into it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I tried to put together some justification in a comment, but it turned into five comments, and then I had to edit and re-post them because I'd made so many grammatical errors.  I hope I managed to get the point across, nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

Usually relative pronouns are preserved in the formal language. However, in this particular case, it would not be grammatical to take out the relative pronoun at all, since the relative pronoun is in the subject position in the relative clause and not followed by a form verb "be".

Comment: Actually some dialects do allow omission of a subject relative pronoun. But not the standard language(s).

Answer (score 1):

Most native speakers probably *would* consider it inappropriate to delete the [relative pronoun](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/relative-pronouns) *"that"* here.

It's not really a matter of "grammar" as such, because there are many contexts where *that, who, which,* etc. can (and often, *should*) be deleted. But *on average*, such deletions aren't so common in formal registers - so much so that less competent writers are sometimes guilty of including *too many*.

To illustrate the formal/informal divide in respect of this construction, consider...

> ***There is** a man wants [to meet you].* [formal - 6 results in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22give%20it%20some%20wellie%22&biw=1232&bih=865&sa=X&ei=FCl0UonZKMmw7AaX0YGoDg&ved=0CCUQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1900,cd_max:12/31/1995&tbm=bks#q=%22There%20is%20a%20man%20wants%22&tbm=bks)
>    ***There's*** a man wants [to meet you]. [informal 3580 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22give%20it%20some%20wellie%22&biw=1232&bih=865&sa=X&ei=FCl0UonZKMmw7AaX0YGoDg&ved=0CCUQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1900,cd_max:12/31/1995&tbm=bks#q=%22There%27s%20a%20man%20wants%22&tbm=bks)
>    *There is a man **who** wants [to meet you].* [formal, "correct" - 120,000 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22give%20it%20some%20wellie%22&biw=1232&bih=865&sa=X&ei=FCl0UonZKMmw7AaX0YGoDg&ved=0CCUQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1900,cd_max:12/31/1995&tbm=bks#q=%22There%20is%20a%20man%20who%20wants%22&tbm=bks)

Note that one shouldn't take this idea of *"that" = "correct"* too far. Consider...

> 1: [There was a girl I knew at school [who used to blah blah]](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22give%20it%20some%20wellie%22&biw=1232&bih=865&sa=X&ei=FCl0UonZKMmw7AaX0YGoDg&ved=0CCUQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1900,cd_max:12/31/1995&tbm=bks#q=%22There%20was%20a%20girl%20I%20knew%20at%20school%22&tbm=bks)
>    2: [There was a girl **that** I knew at school [who used to blah blah]](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22give%20it%20some%20wellie%22&biw=1232&bih=865&sa=X&ei=FCl0UonZKMmw7AaX0YGoDg&ved=0CCUQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1900,cd_max:12/31/1995&tbm=bks#q=%22There%20was%20a%20girl%20that%20I%20knew%20at%20school%22&tbm=bks)

There are at least a handful of results for #1 there, which sounds like normal fluent English to me. And whilst I don't think #2 is "wrong" (some may actually say *only* #2 is "right"), I'd have to say it sounds a little "over-precise" to me. And there are no results for it in Google Books, which I think backs me up on that.

---

EDIT: Apart from the *not really a matter of "grammar"* bit, I stand by what I've said above, and I think it's relevant to note that the rule *You can't omit **that** when it's a subject* isn't universally observed in casual/dialectal speech. But overall, I'm in no doubt @snailboat's answer is more accurate (and concise) than mine.

Comment: No one is saying *"that" = "correct"*, so there's nothing to take too far. *That* can be omitted when it's not a subject (as in the last example, where it's an object) or in some non-standard dialects.

Comment: Examples from *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*, where the relativized elements are respectively: (1) a **subject**, (2) an **object**, (3) a **complement of a preposition**, (4) an **adjunct of time**, (5) an **adjunct of place**, and (6) an **adjunct of reason**: (1) some friends [*who* saw her], (2) a key [*which* she found], (3) those books [*which* I referred to], (4) the day [*when* you were born], (5) a place [*where* you can relax], (6) the reason [*why* she got angry].

Comment: These examples can be replaced with *that*-relatives, which are non-*wh* counterparts.  In these examples, I'll indicate the location of the gap that's co-indexed with *that* explicitly: (1) some friends [*that* \_\_\_\_ saw her], (2) a key [(*that*) she found \_\_\_\_], (3) those books [(*that*) I referred to \_\_\_\_], (4) the day [(*that*) you were born \_\_\_\_], (5) a place [(*that*) you can relax \_\_\_\_], (6) the reason [(*that*) she got angry \_\_\_\_].  Parentheses around *that* indicate that it is optional; it is not optional when the gap is in subject position.

Comment: The non-*wh* counterpart isn't always available, however, which makes the matter of omitting relative pronouns more complicated when you talk about them in general, rather than talking specifically about *that* (like we are in this question).  For example, a *wh*-relative is required to represent adjuncts of place when the head noun doesn't suggest location.  Here's an example from the same book: *This is the web page where the claim was first made*, not **This is the web page the claim was first made.*

Comment: It's good that you're trying to describe the usage you see. Unfortunately, you gave up too early and came to the conclusion that no descriptive rules could be found ("It's not really a matter of 'grammar' as such"). It is a matter of grammar, and you can find the descriptive rules in your grammar of choice; see e.g. *The Syntactic Phenomena of English* (2nd ed.) p.433: "One well-known restriction on internal syntax that applies only to bare relatives is that the gap may not be the main subject of the relative clause."

Answer (score 0):

"**There is** an engine ... **that keeps** saying ...."

"**An engine** inside me **keeps** saying ...."

But still, "engine" seems odd.   I would say "voice".